# Remote desktop control using web application

Tags: java, remote-control, desktop-sharing

We are planning to develop remote desktop sharing feature in out web application (written in Java) where one user will be able to connect other users desktop with full access.

I don't want to use applications like team-viewer. It has to be some kind of web browser plug-in or feature.

I found following couple of solutions like Adobe Connect & Java.awt.Robot class.

Can anyone please let me know best option available?
It will be great if there is any open source project which can satisfy these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try RealVNC out of the box, it has a built in Java web-client that allows full control. Most of the standard flavors of Linux run it, this, of course, totally depends on your user base and what you're trying to do but for an internal tool it is perfect.

http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/man/vncserver.html

The above link is the documentation for VNC server. It can be configured to one-session per port, it is just a matter of making sure the ports are correct. It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel on this one. There's a horde of good free products out there to handle this. For an infinite user-base this probably wouldn't be the best solution. For an internal tool it works wonders.